# How to group array by month - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

I have to group my array by month with key name.

Here is my array and expected result array.

Please help.

```
var data = [
        { 
          _id: "59d34fabe0a967636c7642f2", 
          date: "2019-10-20T18:30:00.000Z", 
        }, 
        { 
          _id: "59d34fab9d1a05ca06ef9775", 
          date: "2019-12-20T18:30:00.000Z", 
        }, 
        { 
          _id: "59d34fab4d49dc45357ab3a5", 
          date: "2019-12-25T18:30:00.000Z", 
        }, 
        { 
          _id: "59d34fab5aa903089e1f9a44", 
          date: "2019-11-24T18:30:00.000Z", 
        }
      ]
```

Expected Result :

```
var result= [
        {
          "2019-10-01" :
          [
            {
              _id: "59d34fabe0a967636c7642f2", 
              date: "2019-10-20T18:30:00.000Z", 
            },
          ] 
        },
        {
          "2019-11-01" :
          [
            { 
              _id: "59d34fab5aa903089e1f9a44", 
              date: "2019-11-24T18:30:00.000Z", 
            }
          ] 
        },
        {
          "2019-12-01" :
          [
            { 
              _id: "59d34fab9d1a05ca06ef9775", 
              date: "2019-12-20T18:30:00.000Z", 
            }, 
            { 
              _id: "59d34fab4d49dc45357ab3a5", 
              date: "2019-12-25T18:30:00.000Z", 
            }
          ] 
        },
      ]
```

Update
[image]
.......................................................................................................

Comment: have you try Array.sort() ? with the month ?

Comment: What about when the data spans more than 12 months? Are all January's grouped together? Or is it year AND month

Comment: year and month... @JonP

Comment: You’ve got some quality answers to choose from. If any solve your question please accept one as the answer… or let us know what we missed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```js
const data = [ { _id: "59d34fabe0a967636c7642f2", date: "2019-10-20T18:30:00.000Z", }, { _id: "59d34fab9d1a05ca06ef9775", date: "2019-12-20T18:30:00.000Z", }, { _id: "59d34fab4d49dc45357ab3a5", date: "2019-12-25T18:30:00.000Z", }, { _id: "59d34fab5aa903089e1f9a44", date: "2019-11-24T18:30:00.000Z", } ];


const sortedObj = {};
data.forEach(e => {                    // loop over all elements
  const k = e.date.slice(0, 7);        // key in YYYY-MM (e.g. 2019-10)
  const fk = `${k}-01`;                // key with appended '-01'   
  sortedObj[fk] = sortedObj[fk] || []; // create new entry if no value for key exists
  sortedObj[fk].push(e);               // add key to existing list
});

const sortedArr = Object.entries(sortedObj).sort((a,b) => new Date(a[0]) - new Date(b[0]));

console.log(sortedArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or as one-liner:

```js
const data = [ { _id: "59d34fabe0a967636c7642f2", date: "2019-10-20T18:30:00.000Z", }, { _id: "59d34fab9d1a05ca06ef9775", date: "2019-12-20T18:30:00.000Z", }, { _id: "59d34fab4d49dc45357ab3a5", date: "2019-12-25T18:30:00.000Z", }, { _id: "59d34fab5aa903089e1f9a44", date: "2019-11-24T18:30:00.000Z", } ];

const sorted = (a = {}, data.forEach(e => { b = e.date.slice(0, 7); c = `${b}-01`; a[c] = a[c] || []; a[c].push(e); }), a = Object.entries(a).sort((a,b) => new Date(a[0]) - new Date(b[0])), a);
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: why not using the sort method ??

Comment: A  good answer explains what it is doing and how it answers the question. At the very least add some comments to your code or use more expressive variable names than `k` and `fk`

Comment: This doesn’t sort the final result like OPs example

Answer (score 2):

A simple [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) loop does the trick. The whole tamale is going to be formatted by [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) which essentially takes our finished array and converts it to an array of objects with key/value pairs. The inner loop is encased in [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) which allows us to iterate the object like an array. The sort is a [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) of the date properties.

```
const months = Object.fromEntries( // convert our final result back into key/values pairs
  Object.entries(data.reduce((b, a) => {  // convert to an iterable array
  let m = a.date.split("T")[0].substr(0, 7) + "-01"; // set up date property for grouping
  if (b.hasOwnProperty(m)) b[m].push(a); else b[m] = [a];  // create or add to accumulating group
  return b; }, {}))
  .sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))) // sort by date property
```

```js
var data = [{
    _id: "59d34fabe0a967636c7642f2",
    date: "2019-10-20T18:30:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "59d34fab9d1a05ca06ef9775",
    date: "2019-12-20T18:30:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "59d34fab4d49dc45357ab3a5",
    date: "2019-12-25T18:30:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "59d34fab5aa903089e1f9a44",
    date: "2019-11-24T18:30:00.000Z",
  }
]
//Object.fromEntries(
const months = Object.entries(data.reduce((b, a) => {
  let m = a.date.split("T")[0].substr(0, 7) + "-01";
  if (b.hasOwnProperty(m)) b[m].push(a); else b[m] = [a];
  return b; }, {}))
  .sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))
  .map(e => ({[e[0]]:e[1]}));
console.log(months)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your data based on month and year in an object accumulator. Then extract all values using `Object.values()`. Then, sort the result based on the date key.

```js
const data = [{ _id: "59d34fabe0a967636c7642f2", date: "2019-10-20T18:30:00.000Z", }, { _id: "59d34fab9d1a05ca06ef9775", date: "2019-12-20T18:30:00.000Z", }, { _id: "59d34fab4d49dc45357ab3a5", date: "2019-12-25T18:30:00.000Z", }, { _id: "59d34fab5aa903089e1f9a44", date: "2019-11-24T18:30:00.000Z", } ],
    grouped = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
      const date = `${o.date.substr(0,7)}-01`;
      r[date] ||= {[date]: []};
      r[date][date].push(o);
      return r;
    }, []))
    .sort((a,b) => Object.keys(a)[0].localeCompare(Object.keys(b)[0]));
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```